# "FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName" returns multiple usernames

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

the currentUser.displayName returns all the users previously logged in the emulator, i have even logged them out using "await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();"

Comment: share some source code for better understanding

Comment: https://github.com/HarshaVardanDonta/tejaswini.git